# Synchronize Data From Event MQTT Endpoint to Device Twin In Azure

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Is there any way which we can automatically sync data between device MQTT events and Device Twin data ?

For a given device in Azure IOT hub there is a mqtt event endpoint and a device twin endpoint associated to it.

I have tried sending MQTT event data to a particular device through device's event MQTT endpoint : devices//messages/events/ and it was successful. I was able to see the incoming data in the device explorer.

The Problem that I have is that, when we send some data to device through device's event mqtt endpoint, those data will not be automatically sync into the respective device's twin. I think it should happen automatically. In azure we have to manually (programmatically) do a twin data push for each event data that we receive through device's event endpoint.

This can be done through pushing mqtt data to device twin endpoint : $iothub/twin/PATCH/properties/reported/?$rid=ID

Is there anyway that we can do it automatically ? - Means automatically synchronize data from event mqtt stream to Device Twin ?

Answer (score 1):

The primary focus of the Azure IoT Hub is to ingest a device telemetry data into the Azure IoT Stream Pipeline in the real time.

Beside that, each device has a capability to save its state in the Azure storage known as a device-twin such as a json formatted document. The device twin has built-in a support for sync the states between the device and backend cloud in the modern event driven distributed architecture.

The differences between the above two communications such as device-to-cloud and device twin is described in the [Reference - IoT Hub quotas and throttling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-quotas-throttling).

Based on this document, you can see, that the device twin is used for non-frequently persistence of the device state, for example: device firmware version, some device configurations, threshold for alert, etc.

In other word, the device twin is not designed for storing a real-time device telemetry data in the cloud backend. In the Internet of things all telemetry data (things) from the devices go to the stream pipeline for their real-time analyzing, etc.

However, the Azure IoT Hub has a capability to help you with your scenario, when a device telemetry data and its device twin changes can be stored in the Azure Blob Storage in the real time, see this feature [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-store-data-in-azure-table-storage). You can use an Azure Function and/or Stream Job for analyzing, query, etc. this blob for your business logic.